# WM8904 and SAMV71 duplicate circuit issues

Tags: audio, codec, atmel

I have been working with SAMV71 Xplained ultra board with some code to loop out the audio of the onboard WM8904 codec. The code works fine on the Xplained ultra board. But when I duplicated a part of the board onto a new PCB I am getting distorted output from the codec. Here are the graphs. Could someone tell me how to debug this? I checked the circuit diagram and tested the PCB and it all looks alright but something is wrong and is causing a distorted output from the codec.
Please let me know what to do here.
[image: Input whistle sound to codec]
[image: Output from codec looks distorted]

LRCLK graph calculated as 43.8 khz freq
[image: LRCLK graph]
BCLK graph calculated as 1.315 Mhz
[image: BCLK grpah]
MCLK graph calculated as 62.5Khz
[image: MCLK graph]

The following is the difference in the BCLK/TK (Synchronous Serial controller Transmitter frequency) which was supposed to be double the current frequency.
[image: BCLK/TK signal in error]

Comment: Anyone could tell me how to debug this problem?

Comment: It kind of looks like a clock signal cross talking on the audio line.  Does the frequency of the sawtooth match any of the other clocks?

Comment: Perhaps someone from the electrical engineering stackexchange can better help with this?: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/